# Is there a way to receive multiple rows from a Django Subquery?

Tags: python, django, orm, subquery

I've been running into this issue multiple times and often end up splitting the subquery from the main query. However I'd like to annotate multiple rows if multiple exist that match the conditions.

`more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Example: Having a contract where either 0, 1 or 2 people have signed it.

Is there any way to annotate multiple results from a subquery?